# Log4j configuration in jsf web app

Tags: jsf-2, log4j

The following configuration is working when I deploy the wep app in my local machine (windows)

```
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    Logger logger = null;
    ServletContext servletContext = sce.getServletContext();
    String prefix = servletContext.getRealPath("/");
    String log4jFile = servletContext.getInitParameter("log4j");       
    if (log4jFile != null) {
        DOMConfigurator.configure(prefix + log4jFile);
        logger = LogManager.getLogger(StartupListener.class.getName());
        logger.info("LOG4J loaded successfully: " + log4jFile);
    }
}

<context-param>
    <param-name>log4j</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/classes/com/domain/resources/log4j.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.domain.util.StartupListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

But when installing the web app in the Linux I get the following error message:

```
log4j:ERROR Could not parse file [nullWEB-INF/classes/com/domain/resources/log4j.xml].
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: /app/home/wdmt3/AdminServer/nullWEB-INF/classes/com/domain/resources/log4j.xml (No such file or directory)
```

Any advice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue resolve by configure properly the weblogic server in order to retrieve the path (domain -> Web Application -> Archived Real Path Enabled)

Answer (score 0):

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4j</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/com/domain/resources/log4j.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**:

- *servletContext.getRealPath* return null and  you log file path become

  ```
    nullWEB-INF/classes/com/domain/resources/log4j.xml
  ```

It's impossible to load this file and log4j just throws an error message you saw.

- So why *servletContext.getRealPath* return null?

The API docs for [ServletContext.getRealPath(String path)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29) state:

> This method returns null if the servlet container is unable to translate the given virtual path to a real path.

Different container may have quite different behavior.

**Solution**:

- Try with the [solution](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-web/3.2.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/web/util/Log4jConfigListener.java#Log4jConfigListener) from spring mvc and make sure log4jFile starts with '/':

  ```
  String log4jFile = servletContext.getInitParameter("log4j"); 
  String fullPath = servletContext.getRealPath(log4jFile);
  ```

Comment: I am not using spring ,basically the only valid option is to change within weblogic the server logging option to log4j

Comment: Have you try the code in my solution? u don't need to use spring actually.

Comment: what do you mean "log4jFile starts with '/'" ?

Comment: /WEB-INF/classes/com/domain/resources/log4j.xml

Comment: u are using weblogic!!! ServletContext.getRealPath() returns null when deployed as WAR but it works ok when deployed as exploded.